# CSS doesnt render on index.html

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, mamp

UPDATE: This has been solved. My CSS selector was wrong. Thank you so much for all who responded!

I am just starting out building a site on a local server using MAMP. I have worked on other people's code but am a sort-of novice when it comes to starting from scratch so forgive my naivety. My CSS file wont apply and give me the proper background color for my header. I have two stylesheets, **style.css** and **960.css** (downloaded from 960.gs).

Upon going to index.html, 960.css renders on the page but style.css is nowhere to be found. They are in the same folder, and called exactly the same on index.html. Please help.

My file structure:

```
-project
   -styles
      style.css
      960.css
   index.html
```

The code is as follows:

index.html

```
<html>
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/960.css"/>
    <title>title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="header_container" class="container_12">
   <div class="grid_2">
    <h1>Title</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and style.css

```
#header_container .container_12 {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

If you are not familiar with the 960 grid system, all it does is provide div classes and measurements for them. The **container_12** you are seeing is in 960.css but is only set with dimensions, not background color so I dont believe it is necessary to include 960.css as it is pretty long. It may be an issue with MAMP, but I'm sure this is a simple mistake somewhere in the code, but I've been working on this issue so long im just braindead at this point. Thank you so much for any input/suggestions you have. If I have not made myself clear anywhere or I need to explain something in more detail please let me know! Thanks again.

Comment: you said they are in the same folder, but you are referring to `styles/style.css`, this should be just `style.css` then.

Comment: I'm sorry, index.html is not in the same folder as the stylesheets. I meant that 960.css and style.css are in the same folder

Comment: any error on the console? Maybe file not found or unable to load etc?

Comment: no error on the console

Comment: In Chrome, use CTRL + U to view page source. After that, click the CSS file path in HTML source. Can you navigate and see the CSS file source in web browser? If path is invalid then web browser cannot navigate you to CSS file.

Comment: Sumeet has solved it. My CSS Selector was wrong. Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS selector you have written is wrong.

```
#header_container .container_12 {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Use

```
#header_container {
      background-color: #000000;
    }
```

or

```
   .container_12 {
      background-color: #000000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the class `.container_12` belongs to "960.css" and you are trying to force the class in your `style.css`, if yes, try to update your css (!important) like below..

**CSS:**

```
.container_12 {
  background-color: #000000!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you selector wasn't wrong, you were only violating group selector's rule and a couple of things. However to use group selectors, you need to separate each selector with a "," not space. so you should have something like this;

```
#header_container, .container_12 {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

But I wonder why you are passing the same property and value to the same div element with a class and an id?
Good luck.